# Doxygen documents my Objective-C Code as though it is C++

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I want to set up doxygen as the tool to document my Objective C source code.  The code generating tool seems to work well, except that the way it renders the descriptions of my Objective C methods makes them look like they are written in C++.  I have read through all of the various options in the [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) website, but I can't find a combination of options to force it to render a more "Objective-C"-like appearance.

Likewise, editing the doxygenLayout.xml file seems to be useful for changing the names of the different sections, but I don't see how it can be used to change the way that methods are represented.  I have included an example below:

[image: My Source Code]

[image: The Resulting Documentation]

Notice how version has two parenthesis after it, and the class uses two colons between the class name and the method name.  Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Doxygen obviously interprets 'version' wrongly as a C++ method in your case, but it normally would auto-detect obj-C code. Trying your example in a .h file with a default config file does not show this problem, so if you manage to capture it in a self-contained example, please submit a bug in doxygen's bugtracker for it and attach the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It seems that bumping up from 1.7.5.1 to 1.7.6 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `Doxyfile` for `EXTENSION_MAPPING` (or try starting with a clean `Doxyfile`). I've had decent success using Doxygen with ObjC (not perfect, but pretty good) using the default settings.

What version of Doxygen are you using? I'm still using 1.6.1, but I wouldn't expect a massive change in the 1.7 line.

Comment: I was using 1.7.5.1 but there was just a new release and changing to the newest version fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force doxygen to generate documentation for Objective-C, you can use EXTENSION_MAPPING in doxygens config file. For example, if you want to force doxygen to Objective-C for .m and .h files, add the following:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = m=Objective-C \
                         h=Objective-C
```